# Google-CDN does not change the path to CDN leaves it at bower_components

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I am trying to run the google-cdn plugin via Gulp (gulp-google-cdn) to covert bower references in my HTML file into the CDN equivalent.  Gulp-google-cdn does not do anything, and enabling the DEBUG, shows: `google-cdn Could not find satisfying version for angular-material ^1.0.5`

My task (I use a subdirectory with tasks per file):

```
gulp.task('HTML:Release', function() {
    return gulp.src('../src/*.html')
        .pipe(googleCdn(require('../bower.json')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist/') )
    ;
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="OntarioDarts" ng-cloak lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body layout="row" ng-cloak>
    <div layout="column" class="relative" layout-fill role="main">
        <md-content flex md-scroll-y>
            <ng-view></ng-view>
        </md-content>
    </div>
</body>


<!-- Load JavaScript Last for Speed. Load from CDN for cache speed -->
<!-- Angular JS -->
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material-icons/angular-material-icons.min.js"></script>
```

The distribution file does not point Angular to the CDN, but still tries to use the bower_components, even though it did not complain that the files were not found.

One problem I found is that I have Angular set at ^1.5.0 in my bower.json. However, I was only using the default Google CDN, which does not currently have the 1.5.0 available. I changed the version in the bower.json file to be ^1.4.0, and then the file was changed to use the CDN with version 1.4.7.

The problem though is that the reference did not get changed to HTTPS://, but was left simply as `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Gulp-google-cdn does not do anything, and enabling the DEBUG, shows: `google-cdn Could not find satisfying version for angular-material ^1.0.5`

That's because the newest version available from the Google CDN [is 1.0.4](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#angular-material).

> The problem though is that the reference did not get changed to HTTPS://, but was left simply as `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"`

That's not necessarily a problem. That's a [protocol-relative URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protocol-relative).  If your page is served over HTTP, `angular.min.js` is fetched over HTTP. If your page is served over HTTPS, `angular.min.js` is fetched over HTTPS.

Unless you absolutely need `angular.min.js` to always be fetched over HTTPS you can just leave it like that.

**EDIT:** ... except for when you're trying to open a local HTML file in a browser. Then your protocol is `file://` and the protocol relative URL will refer to your local file system. Which of course leads nowhere.

One way of fixing this would be to serve your html files through a locally running webserver (e.g. with [gulp-webserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-webserver)). When your HTML pages come from e.g. `http://localhost:8000/` all the protocol relative URLs will be served over `http://` as well.

If you just want all the CDN URLs to be prefixed with `https://` instead, here's a way to wrap the [google-cdn-data](https://github.com/shahata/google-cdn-data/) object to achieve this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var googleCdn = require('gulp-google-cdn');
var jp = require('jsonpath');

function protocol(proto, cdn) {
    jp.apply(cdn, '$.*.url', function(url) {
        return function(version) {
            return proto + url(version);
        };
    });
    return cdn;
}

gulp.task('HTML:Release', function() {
    return gulp.src('../src/*.html')
        .pipe(googleCdn(require('./bower.json'), {
             cdn: protocol('https:', require('google-cdn-data'))
         }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist/') );
});
```

You'll need to run `npm install --save-dev google-cdn-data jsonpath` for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I found the version problem and updated my question for that as the CDNs are not as up to date yet.   My issue is in running locally in my development environment, where the src="//..." does not work.  I get a browser error and the files are not loaded.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.